# OpenGL - using gluSphere

Tags: opengl, rendering, models, sphere

I have an OpenGL code that currently draws several spheres at different locations. I generate the vertex buffer data (and normal data) myself. However, to simplify the code and increase efficiency, I am now trying to use gluSphere instead. The problem is that if I want to draw several spheres at different locations, I think I will need several different model matrices, and thus several different MVP matrices (because I am using OpenGL 4.3 and there is no glTranslate). But if I want to rotate the whole scene, I will need to rotate all of these model matrices, instead of just one as before. Is there a workaround for this? Is there a simple way to draw several different things with gluQuadrics objects at different locations?

Comment: Don't switch to gluSphere. It's unlikely going to increase efficiency and it will only make the code more complex when you have non-GLU objects as well.

Comment: @msell I see. But I'm still concerned that my code is somewhat inefficient. Is there any alternative solution, or should I just try fixing my own code?

Comment: Take a look at [instancing](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing).

Comment: If you are using polygonal spheres, also consider using [impostors](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tutorial%2013.html)